# Semantic-ui Tabular Menu not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron, semantic-ui

Hy, i'm trying to build an Electron app that uses Semantic UI. At the moment, i'm trying to implement a tabular menu as shown in the basic tab example, and this is the behavior i'm trying to implement: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#basic-tabs.

My code seems to be all right but the menu isn't behaving as expected. In the image below you can see that the content of the div's just appears down the others, as a normal div html section.

[image]

Well, in my research i found that we have to put somethiing like

```
<script>
  var $ = require('jquery');
  $('.item').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

And i did, just don't know if the right way. After that the functionality of changing the pressed button is working, i.e. if i press the "second" button the ui render correctly, lik image below. And so on with the other possible tabs.

[image]

I've already did the following steps:

-> Import jQuery via NPM with `npm install jquery --save` and this gave me "jquery": "^3.5.1" on my package.json file.

My full code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui visible left demo vertical inverted thin sidebar labeled icon menu">
        
      <a class="item" href="index.html">
        <i class="tint icon"></i>
        Análise
      </a>
      <a class="item" href="resultados.html" style="color: aquamarine;">
        <i class="chart bar icon" style="color: aquamarine;"></i>
        Gráficos
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pusher">
      <div class="ui basic segment">
        <div style="width: 80%; margin: 2%;">     
            <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
                <a class="item active" data-tab="hidrogenio">
                Níveis de hidrogenio
                </a>
                <a class="item" data-tab="etano">
                Photos
                </a>
                <a class="item" data-tab="etileno">
                    Etileno
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="ui bottom attached segment" data-tab="hidrogenio">
              <p>First Tab</p>
            </div>

            <div class="ui bottom attached segment" data-tab="etano">
              <p>Second Tab</p>
            </div> 

            <div class="ui bottom attached segment" data-tab="etileno">
              <p>Third Tab</p>
            </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script>require('./js/renderer')</script>
</body>
<script>
  var $ = require('jquery');
  $('.item').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
</html>
```

I don't know why the div with the data-tab aren't working as expected and remain "hidden" until we press the respective button...

I'd appreciate so much the help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after looking on your code and checking the documentation which I post below the basics:

```html
<!-- The basic format for a tabular menu -->
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="active item" data-tab="first">First</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="third">Third</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached active tab segment" data-tab="first">
  First
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
  Second
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
  Third
</div>
```

and the JS code:

```js
// the require js code to make semantic read that html as a tabular menu
$('.menu .item')
  .tab()
;
```

I don't see the required JS part on your code, just the actions your script will run when you click an item. You really need the JS code part I posted in order for that to work.